# Javascript Fetch improved error message on connection refused

Tags: javascript, error-handling, fetch-api

When `fetch` fails due to connection refused, as well as other conditions, the Error thrown has name `TypeError` and message `Failed to fetch`.

I would like to call `alert()` with a more meaningful message for the user that gives a better indication of the cause - such as `Conenction Refused`.

It appears the browser logs the more specific cause in the javascript console.  Is it possible to obtain the more specific error from the fetch results?

Comment: I suspect there isn't any way to get a better error.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's likely so.  Guess it's not a big enough problem for most javascript apps out there.